# Question regarding dimension when creating an EAGLE Footprint

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, footprint

[image]

Hi so i was trying to create a footprint based on this dimension. But i'm not quite sure what these two numbers mean exactly? Are they MAX/MIN? Which one should i use? Thank you!

Comment: Should be dimensioning and tolerances, as stated in first note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dimension means the Maximum and Minimum size. You need to use the maximum size to avoid interference.
And the data inside brackets are inch unit.(Former size data means in millimeter.)

Comment: but i have checked other datasheets of other ICs. It seems to me that the max/min difference is too big. For this one, isn't almost 2 mm difference too off?

Comment: @YihanHu Here is a specification of DIP package of Maxim. Refer to it.  https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/package_dwgs/21-0244.PDF